# What is HttpClient? And how do I get it?

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm testing out a Java applet uploader that uploads via HTTP. They have also provided some server side files written in .NET that handle the upload.

When I try to run the applet, it gives me the following error:

```
You can't use http upload functionality because HttpClient library not installed on server.
```

I'm running Windows Server 2003 with IIS6.

I'm really not sure what I need to do at this point to get this working. Does anyone know what I need to download and install?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a Java library (since your question is tagged with Java), then possibly [the Apache Commons HttpClient library](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)

But it's likely that you're looking for something dotnet, and in that case, there is a [Microsoft library of same name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It sounds funny that a "client" library would be needed on the server, instead of on the client, but anything is possible.

Comment: It's an IIS Server, so the use of a Java Library isn't quite possible.

Comment: I saw that, but the question was tagged with Java.

Comment: Turned out to be a problem with the old files. Al working now.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a problem with the old files. Al working now. – Julian Dormon just now edit